# ETag format w3c

Tags: http, http-headers, w3c, etag

We use ETag header for syncronization on server and it corresponds to entities 'int version' field in DB.
According to w3c docs:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
Examples:

```
  ETag: "xyzzy"
  ETag: W/"xyzzy"
  ETag: ""
```

It means that ETag inside double quotes.
So if I want to send it to client it should be done like:

```
int version = 2;
response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ETAG, String.format("\"%s\"", version));
```

Or:

```
 int version = 2;
 response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ETAG, String.format("%s", version));
```

In first case I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
ETag: 2
```

In second:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
ETag: "2"
```

Which way is more w3c compliant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) the W3C doesn't matter. You are looking at a copy of the IETF RFC 2616, hosted by the W3C. And that RFC is obsoleted, you should read RFC 7232 (for instance http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7232.html#header.etag).

b) Of your examples, the first one is incorrect, and the second one is correct.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that 2616 is obsolete.